# How to load Groovy classes into the Groovy script engine of Activiti?

Tags: groovy, activiti

I am loading a Groovy project with the following structure in Activiti :

```
└───src
    └───main
        └───groovy
            ├───classes
            │       Foo.groovy
            │
            └───scripts
                    script.groovy
```

**script.groovy**

```
package scripts

import classes.Foo
```

**Foo.groovy**

```
package classes

class Foo {
  Foo(){
  }
}
```

My problem is that the import statement of my script: `import classes.Foo` is not resolved by Activiti.

I am running Activiti inside a Spring container using `org.activiti:activiti-spring:5.21.0`. My scripts are evaluated using the groovy scripting engine in `org.activiti-engine:5.21.0`.

**How to make Activiti aware of my `Foo.groovy` class ?**

I have been looking for a way to specify the classpath but no luck so far.

I tried to manually resolve the import statements from the files and evaluate them but I am not satisfied with this solution.

I see that Activiti uses the scripting engine [GroovyScriptEngineImpl](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/jsr223/GroovyScriptEngineImpl.html) to evaluate my script.

Comment: You've already asked this question. And the answer would be the same. Add the root folder with classes into your classpath. No matter if it's activiti or pure groovy.

Comment: @daggett _Add the root folder with classes into your classpath_ This is exactly what I am trying to achieve through Activiti. I know this is the solution to my problem but I cannot find how to specify my classpath to Activiti.

Comment: @daggett All I know is how to do that through a command line instruction with `groovy -cp <classpath> <file>`

Comment: Please edit your question and provide info how do you run activiti. Is it a webapp under tomcat or other way?

Comment: @daggett I added some more information

Comment: Have you tried adding your classpath to the ApplicationContext?
You can explicitly set the classpath (:classpath) on each of your beans

Comment: Try to set classpath for your java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do that using [GroovyClassLoader#parseClass()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#parseClass(groovy.lang.GroovyCodeSource)) method.

```
final GroovyScriptEngineImpl engine = (GroovyScriptEngineImpl) this.scriptingEngines.getEngineByName("groovy");
GroovyClassLoader classLoader = engine.getClassLoader();
Files.walk(...)
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .forEach(path -> {
        classLoader.parseClass(new GroovyCodeSource(path.toUri()));
    });
engine.setClassLoader(classLoader);
```